# error "Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host." when pushing to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

when i try to push some data (like x.txt) to gitlab it's success. but when i try push my project, show this error. here is my command :

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:armafri/new.git
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "test"
$ git push origin master
```

this is that error

> Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host.
>   fatal: sha1 file '' writeerror: Broken pipe
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyerror: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:armafri/new.git'

I have tried this command

```
$ git config http.postBuffer 72428800
```

but still show that error.
can you help me please?

ps :
 1. file size is only 70mb
 2. i've tried git push -u or --force

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same problem too